# Speed up ListLinePlot

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, plot

I am trying to use Mathematica to analyse some raw data. I'd like to be able to dynamically display the range of data I'm interested in using `Manipulate` and `ListLinePlot`, but the plot rendering is extremely slow. How can I speed it up?

Here are some additional details. An external text file stores the raw data: the first column is a timestamp, the second, third and fourth columns are data readings, for example:

```
1309555993069, -2.369941, 6.129157, 6.823794
1309555993122, -2.260978, 6.170018, 7.014479
1309555993183, -2.070293, 6.129157, 6.823794
1309555993242, -1.988571, 6.238119, 7.123442
```

A single data file contains up to 2·10<sup>6</sup> lines. To display, for example, the second column, I use:

```
x = Import["path/to/datafile"];
ListLinePlot[x[[All, {1, 2}]]]
```

The execution time of this operation is unbearably long. To display a variable range of data I tried to use `Manipulate`:

```
Manipulate[ListLinePlot[Take[x, numrows][[All, {1, 2}]]], {numrows, 1, Length[x]}]
```

This instruction works, but it quickly crawls when I try to display more than few thousand lines. How can I speed it up?

Some additional details:

- MATLAB displays the same amount of data on the same computer almost instantaneously, thus the raw data size shouldn't be an issue.
- I already tried to turn off graphics antialiasing, but it didn't impact rendering speed at all.
- Using `DataRange` to avoid `Take` doesn't help.
- Using `MaxPlotPoints` distorts too much the plot to be useful.
- Not using `Take` in `Manipulate` doesn't help.
- The rendering seems to take huge amount of time. Running `Timing[ListLinePlot[Take[x,100000][[All, {1, 2}]]]]` returns `0.33`: this means that the evaluation of `Take` by itself is almost instantaneous, is the plot rendering that slows everything down.
- I am running Mathematica on Ubuntu Linux 11.10 using the fglrx drivers. Forcing Mathematica to use mesa drivers didn't help.

Any hint?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't tested extensively this on my machine (I have a Mac, so I can't rule out Linux-specific issues). but a couple of points occur to me. The following was pretty quick for me, but obviously slower than if the data set was smaller. You are plotting hundreds of thousands of data points.

```
data = Accumulate@RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 200000];
Manipulate[ListLinePlot[Take[data, n]], {n, 1, Length[data]}]
```

1. In a `Manipulate`, you are allowing the amount of data shown with `Take` to vary arbitrarily. Try only incrementing `numrows` every 100 or so points, so there is less to render.
2. Try using the `ContinuousAction->False` option (see [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ContinuousAction.html)) (I see @Szabolcs had the same idea as I was typing.
3. I was about to suggest `MaxPlotPoints`, but instead try the `PerformanceGoal ->"Speed"` option. (see [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PerformanceGoal.html))

Comment: Using a reasonable value for `MaxPlotPoints` and using `PerformanceGoal` did the trick. The rendering is still worse than the MATLAB's one, but it is much better than before, thanks!

Comment: What is `PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"` actually doing?  I thought it just reduced `MaxPlotPoints`.

Comment: @giuseppe what value of `MaxPlotPoints` did you use? I feel the number of pixels in your figure (`ImageSize`) or on your screen would be a good choice. At 1000, Verbeia's data plots extremely fast. It's on my screen before my finger is able to get off the enter key. Quality is very good.

Comment: @Sjoerd that's what I said in my other comment, but actually if the fluctuations in the data are very strong, then any reduction in `MaxPlotPoints` can have an effect on appearance, regardless of pixel width.  On the other hand with such strong fluctuations one can't see a lot on a small figure.

Comment: @Sjoerd, consider e.g. `rv = RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[2], 10000];` `ListLinePlot[rv, PlotRange -> All, MaxPlotPoints -> 1000]` `ListLinePlot[rv, PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: @Sjoerd, e.g. if you have one strong peak somewhere consisting of a single data point, it's likely to be removed by downsampling the data.

Comment: @szabolcs in that case there is no possible way matlab could present the data better. Only thing I can think of is smoothing, like 'MovingAverage' or a 'ListConvolve'

Comment: @Sjoerd, I guess he just meant that Matlab can render the full (not reduced) data faster.  Indeed, there's no reason there could be any significant "quality" difference in rendering other than antialiasing.  At least the versions of Matlab I'm familiar with don't do antialiasing.

Comment: @giuseppe, you can always revert to the pre-version-6 graphics behaviour with ``<< Version5`Graphics` ``, and use `ListPlot[data, PlotJoined->True]`, which will give you very fast rendering for a million datapoints.  But this has so many other disadvantages and incompatibilities with post-6 features that it's very difficult to make it useful.

Answer (score 12):

If your goal is to just visualize your data quickly but properly, you can use the following trick, which I am constantly using.

I partition the data into a number of blocks corresponding roughly to the resolution of my screen (usually 1000 or less), more detail cannot be displayed anyway. Then I determine the Min and Max of each block, and draw a zig-zag line from min to max to min to max... The result will look exactly like the original data. You can however not "zoom in", as you would then see the zig-zag line (e.g. when exporting to high-res pdf). Then you need to use a larger number of blocks.

```
rv = RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[2], 100000];

ListLinePlot[rv, PlotRange -> All] (* original, slow *)
ListLinePlot[rv, PlotRange -> All, MaxPlotPoints -> 1000] (* fast but distorted *)

numberOfBlocks = 1000;

ListLinePlot[Riffle @@ Through[{Min /@ # &, Max /@ # &}[
   Partition[rv,Floor[Length[rv]/numberOfBlocks]]]], PlotRange -> All]
```

You can add the `DataRange->{...}` option to label the x-axis appropriately.

Hope this helps!

EDIT:
See also this similar question on Mathematica Stackexchange:
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/140/58

Comment: Nice --- I didn't see this when I posted my Jul 26 answer.

Answer (score 5):

I also noticed that occasionally Mathematica will take too long to render graphics.  Actually it must be some translation step from a Mathematica `Graphics` expression to some other representation that takes long because once rendered, resizing (and thus re-rendering) the graphic is much faster.  Pre-version-6 graphics rendering used to be faster for many examples (but also lacks a lot of functionality that 6+ have).

Some ideas about what you could do:

1. Use the `MaxPlotPoints` option of `ListLinePlot` to reduce the data before plotting.  It might not make a difference in looks if its downsampled.  The `Method` option should choose the downsample algorithm, but I can't find any docs for it (anyone?)
2. Use `ContinuousAction -> False` in `Manipulate` to stop it from recomputing everything in real time as you drag the sliders.

Comment: +1 just for mentioning `MaxPlotPoints`, which I did not know about

Comment: And +1 for beating me to ContinuousAction :)

Comment: I am sorry that my question wasn't clear. `ContinuousAction -> False` would certainly help, but the plotting procedure is extremely slow even for ListLinePlot[Take[x, 100000][[All, {1, 2}]]], and `MaxPlotPoints` distorts the plot too much to be useful (strangely, even if I use it the plot time doesn't decrease appreciably)

Comment: Are you sure you can't use `MaxPlotPoints`?  The graphic is only so many pixels wide (certainly much much less than 10^6!), and it makes no sense to use more points than the pixel-width at most.

Comment: You're right, I was using a value too high for `MaxPlotPoints`. The rendering is of lower quality compared to MATLAB's one and is much slower, anyway it is better than before. I am accepting Verbeia's answer because he suggested using `PerformanceGoal`, that seems to help. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 5):

Another idea here is using the [Ramer–Douglas–Peucker algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) to reduce the number of data points before plotting.  This will likely preserve the shape of the data better.  I don't know if you still need this so I won't provide an implementation.

Comment: I wrote an answer using the Peucker algorithm with a little animation that may be interesting.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/36937976/2836621